# Cannot access Workout Exercises on Google Fitness API

Tags: android, google-play-services, wear-os, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

Using the tutorial (https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started), I was able to use the Fitness API to retrieve basic data such as steps. However, I have been unable to retrieve any `DataSource` related to `DataType.TYPE_WORKOUT_EXERCISE`.

Any ideas if workout exercises require any extra libraries or have any specific hardware requirements?

Here are my specs:

```
Handheld device: Nexus 5 on Android 5.1.1 using the latest Play Services 7.5.0
Wearable device: Moto 360 E939 on Android 5.0.2
```

**edit**

This is also the only documentation I can find regarding `WorkoutExercises`:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/WorkoutExercises

Comment: My initial reading suggested the WorkoutExercises was just a data type for passing data to the Google FIT API to be stored and couldn't actually be used to figure out what kind of exercise is going on.

Comment: That would be odd if that were the case, since WorkoutExercises are categorized as Google Fit `DataTypes`. The way it's documented, all `DataTypes` have corresponding `DataSources` with the same ability to be listened via `Fitness.sensorApi.add(...)`.

Comment: I was looking into this just today as well and couldn't find anything, hence my conclusion. If you look at the link you posted and the code on it, the comment says: "Exercises can be entered using the TYPE_WORKOUT_EXERCISE data type. Here's an example of creating a data point to represent 10 repetitions of bicep curls with a weight of 20kg"
That is the only instance I can find of any of the exercise constants ever being used! My conclusion it is mechanism to record these things (assuming you get data from somewhere or the user inputs it). I was looking into how they determin "resistence".

Comment: I'm sorry I can't bring up a link, but during this year's I/O live stream for Workout Fitness data, they had a demonstration of a user exercising (situps and squats, if I recall), with the app receiving the exercise actions in real time.